# Android send file as byte array using json to asp.net api

Tags: android, asp.net, arrays, json, api

I am trying to send file to SQL server using Asp.net MVC API, the file goes as byte array using `Json object`,but the API gets a `null` parameter object instead of the `byte array` and the other data.
Is there any way to send the file and the other data to the server?

Following is the android code

```
byte[] bytes;
File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
fileName=file.getName();
int si = (int) file.length();
bytes = new byte[si];

try {
    BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    int y=bytes.length;
    buf.close();
    new UserUploadTask().execute((Void) null);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

private boolean uploadFile() {
    try {
        String url = String.format("http://site/api/UploadFile");
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream printout;
        JSONObject j=new JSONObject();
        j.put("mn",serMobileNum);
        j.put("File",arr);
        j.put("title",title);
        j.put("size",size);
        j.put("name",fileName);
        j.put("type",1);
        String msg = j.toString();
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        conn.connect();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(msg);
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        Log.i("info", "read");
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        String FinalString = sb.toString();
        if(FinalString.contains("true")) {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not sending the file. Or the bytes of the file. Or your byte array.

Comment: `j.put("File",arr);`. We do not know the type of arr nor what it contains.

Comment: arr it is byte[] arr = bytes

Comment: What kind of file is it? Normally one cannot put a byte array in this way as the value for a json parameter.

Comment: `String msg = j.toString();`. Have you tried to log that msg string? Please tell what you saw.

Comment: file type : pdf,zip,docx

Comment: this is the result :{"mn":"012","File":"[B@3009f8c7","title":"gg","size":0,"name":"1546961091.pdf","type":1}

Comment: Well i miss your comment on this. Is the file included? Are all the arr bytes included? What was the size of the file? What was the length of the bytes array? What is the length of this json string? Do you think that the content of the file will be send by this json string?

Comment: And if have answered all those questions then please tell where things go wrong.

Comment: Do a test with a small plain text file. A .txt file. Only two lines.  Then you can see it included in the json string if you adapt your code a little.

Comment: You can as wel `Log.d("File",arr);` to see what you do wrong.

Comment: `j.put("File",arr);`. arr should be a String in order that j.put() will work.

Comment: Have a look at `arr.toString()`. Does it look familiar?

Comment: I think that arr does not contain all bytes of the file ,and after all it goes as string not as bytes

Comment: You made two nonsense comments. Please be serious.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: what i meant is that the arr does not contain all the bytes of the file , and its sent as a string when j.put("File",arr); not as bytes

Comment: Yes. But you only repeat yourself and react insufficiat to my remarks. Dubug better please. Arr is sent as a string. In fact arr.toString() is sent. That why i said you to have a look and to see that familiar string. arr.toString() does not represent the content of the arr bytes. So please tell how you checked that it does contain less bytes than it should. Have a look at arr.length too. (Or arr.length()). You are not sending the arr bytes but arr.toString(). Which is wrong. Now take that .txt file and tell all the sizes. Start debugging.

Comment: Okay. the length of the arr is about 500,000 the size of the file , but the length of the arr.toString() is just 10 ! . how can i send the real bytes not the wrong string ?.

Comment: Not only that. You use json. And want to put the file in a json parameter. Json parameter values can only be strings. So you cannot send that array.  It looks as if you meanwhile did not any research or google action. If you had you would have known by long that you should encode the bytes of the file to a base64 encoded string.

Comment: i did that ,encode the file to base64 string ,but it takes a long time to encode ,so i tried to send bytes to server

Comment: It is indeed much better to send the bytes of the file directly. Dont use json for uploading files.